# How to add a custom CA to androids trusted root system folder

Tags: certificates, android, certificate-authority, root

As of Android 7.0 no custom certificate will be used by android apps. App developers need to specifically write codes and change app settings to follow a custom CA.

But this is difficult while testing for certificate pinning in a UAT environment. As a solution I wanted to add the custom CA certificate of my proxy tool (burp or ZAP) to androids system folder.

How to do this? To which folder the certificate needs to be copied? I am using an emulator. So is there a way to do this without rooting the emulator?

Ref: First answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40097307/4202092).

Answer (score 1):

[Magisk](https://github.com/NVISO-BE/MagiskTrustUserCerts) claims to do this.

> This module makes all installed user certificates part of the system certificate store, so that they will automatically be used when building the trust chain.

Comment: That tool feels so dangerous, if it does what it claims